# How to turn low/high values into 0.10 and 1.00 exponentially?

Tags: exponential-function

Let's say I got an array of several numbers, I know the highest one is $115$ (for example) and the lowest one is $9$. I want to turn a middle number into a decimal value in a exponential way.

For example

Highest value: $115$

Lowest value: $9$

$9 = 0.1$ (lowest decimal)

$115 = 1.0$ (highest decimal)

$67 = 0.$??

How would be the formula for this? I'm sorry if the question is a little dumb.

Comment: The way I understand it, you're asking about [logarithmic scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale). I recommend reading up on what these entail - it seems like that could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite similar to converting $^0F$ to $^0C$.

1. Calculate the ranges for both. They are respectively (115 - 9) and (1 - 0.1)

   2. Calculate the offsets from the starting points. They are respectively (67 - 9) and (x - 0.1); where x is the required.
   3. Setup the ratio $\dfrac {1 - 0.1}{115 - 9} = \dfrac {x - 0.1}{67 - 9}$.

Comment: The "x" means how much the line will be bowed?

Comment: The "x" is the actual value in the new scale.

Comment: The op wanted it to be be exponential.  This is linear.  It's not at all the same.  The line will not be bowed at all.

Comment: @fleablood  All I can say is a linear graph is a special case of an exponential graph.

Comment: That is true.  I can not argue with that.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$y =  \exp(\alpha x + \beta )$$

$$\ln (y) = \alpha x + \beta$$

Solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Is there any math way to turn this formula into just one? Thanks anyway.

Comment: It is just one formula. Those two equations are equivalent, I write it in the second form as it might be more familiar for you to solve for slope and intercept of a linear line.

Answer (score 0):

You want $e^{kx + t}$ where $x = 9$ yields $e^{9k + t} = .1$ so $9k + t = \ln .1$ and $ e^{115k + t} = 1$ so $115k + t = \ln 1 = 0$ so $t = -115k$.

$9k + t = 9k - 115k = -106k = \ln .1$ so $k = -\frac {\ln .1}{106} \approx 0.0217$ and $t = -115*\frac{\ln .1}{106}$

So $f(x) = e^{(115-x)\frac {\ln .1}{106}}= (.1)^{\frac {115-x}{106}}= 10^{\frac {x-115}{106}}$

So $f(67) = 10^{\frac{67-115}{106}} \approx 10^{-.4528} \approx .35$.

Comment: Thank you but I'll stick with the easier one because it's for programming purposes and needs lesser CPU usage, but thank you anyway.